# The git push stops at writing objects 99%

Tags: git

I created a new branch from master branch.
But after I changed something and `git add` and `commit`, I did `git push origin HEAD`, but the log showed:

```
Counting objects: 117, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
Writing objects:  99% (116/117), 1.30 MiB | 7.00 KiB/s
```

Some people tell me to try:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But I tried it on the `~` location, but no use.

So how to fix this?

Comment: What kind of files are you pushing ? Any log files or really big ones ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna The size is 804.7MB

Comment: If the file is that huge, it would take about 10-15 minutes. Howlong have you been waiting for ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna About 30 minutes

Comment: Can you do this in the sameplace as you're doing git push, but before it `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

Comment: I have never tried pushing such large files, max being 250MB and it took me between 10-15min. So I would ask you to wait. However, you can try increasing the buffer size to 500MB and see what happens. I would still suggest you to wait and see.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Yeah! It pushes completely now, and this cost 50 min.

Comment: Damn, I hope you don't have to push files this large in size frequently :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `git remote -v` output for 'origin': it depends on the protocol used (https or ssh)

HTTPS would involved an HTTPS listener on the remote side, which can be limited on the size it accepts (no matter how big you set `http.postBuffer` on your client side)

You can switch to SSH and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It might simply be taking a long time to upload the added file. The log shows the upload is happening at 7KiB/s. At that speed an 804Mb file will take around 31 hours!

Git's progress indicator `Writing objects:  99% (116/117)` seems to be based only on the number of objects, it doesn't account for their size. So it's common for it to appear to freeze when the operation gets to a large file.

Comment: "Yeah! It pushes completely now, and this cost 50 min."

Glad to see it completed eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it is because my VPN, when I close the Global mode and open the Auto mode, the push will run fast.